# General purpose per-project name-value collection in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

On-premises TFS 2015 update 2. I need to attach some arbitrary scalar attributes (reasonably short text strings) to my team projects. Need REST API access for reading them (not necessarily for writing). Everyone can read them, only TFS admins can write them. Read often, written rarely. Logically, they're a part of our release management infrastructure (as opposed to, say, source control or issue tracking).

I can see several convoluted ways to do that. For example, I could create a file with a hard-coded name in the source control root for the project. I could create a service endpoint with a magic name and sufficiently URL-like data. I could create a work item. But all those approaches are, well, ugly workarounds, exercises in repurposing unrelated project level data structures.

Is there a straightforward way, please? Direct access to the underlying TFS SQL database is a no-no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TFS 2017, there's the Library, aka Variable Groups, under the Build&Release section. It's exactly what I was looking for - a general purpose, project scoped, programmatically accessible set of named name-value collections.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you could use labels to achieve what you're looking for. These can be applied to any file or folder within your collection (including projects). Labels have names and comments, and can be accessed by the TFS Rest API.

To apply one through Visual Studio (2015 is what I'm using), right click on the file or folder in Source Control Explorer > Advanced > Apply Label...

To access labels using the TFS Rest API, you can [view the documentation here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/labels). Here is an example using PowerShell to get all labels for a project:

```
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://YourTfsServer:8080/tfs/YourCollection/YourProject/_apis/tfvc/labels?api-version=1.0-preview.1" -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get
$labels = $($result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).Value
write $labels
```

If you're concerned about permissions, you might be able to disable "low privilege" users from creating labels. I could not find that security setting for TFS 2015, but I know it exists in previous versions, and maybe I just didn't find it. You could also read labels created only by certain users.